# android ant build file use in both windows and linux system?

Tags: android, ant

I made an ant build.xml file on linux, which builds successfully.

On windows, the same build fails.

Is it possible to build on windows and linux with the same build.xml?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  A properly written ant script can run on multiple OS's.  But there is no general answer to your question.  You need to provide specific details of the failure.

Comment: Is it the `build.xml` using linux line endings which is different to windows, that iis causing the issue been experienced? Try re-saving it with windows line endings, use notepad2 to help!

Comment: how did it fail on windows?